# Running a regression in R markdown file produces a set of results in RStudio and different set of results in the knitted Word file. Why?

Tags: r, markdown

Running a regression in R markdown file produces a set of results in RStudio and different set of results in the knitted Word file. The results in RStudio appear to be the correct ones. I wonder what could be going on.

Comment: Without your data, markdown and code, who can say?

Comment: Fair point. I figured it out. I was doing random sampling in the code, and so I learned that the knitted document reruns the code hence will sample randomly from scratch so unless one fixed the seed with set.seed(999) this problem will happen. In fact the results in the RStudio session will be different from those in the knitted Word file, and both of those would be different from the knitted pdf file. Lesson learned.